# 405 during Feign client GET

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, microservices

Im currently trying to perform a GET method on my "Courses" microservice controller. But when i try to fetch i get a 405 error code.

The general idea is that i perform a GET on the "Courses" microservice to get objects by id from the "Purchases" microservice.

1. Feign class in the purchases where im performing a GET

```
@FeignClient(value = "COURSES", configuration = {
        FeignConfig.class
})
public interface CourseService {
    @GetMapping("/courses/all-by-id")
    CoursesByIdResponse getAllByCourseIds(@RequestBody CourseIdsRequest courseIds);
}
```

Course Controller

```
@RestController()   
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
public class CourseController {
    
    private final CoursePaginatedService courseService;

    public CourseController(@Qualifier("paginatedService") CoursePaginatedService courseService) {
        this.courseService = courseService;
    }


    @GetMapping("/courses/all-by-id")
    public ResponseEntity<CoursesByIdResponse> getAllByCourseIds(@RequestBody CourseIdsRequest       courseIds){
         return ResponseEntity.ok(courseService.getAllByCourseIds(courseIds.getCourseIds()));
    }

}
```

I have more methods in the Course controller that work propperly (200 ok).

```
@GetMapping("/courses/course/{id}") 
public ResponseEntity<CourseByIdResponse> getCourseById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long id){
    return ResponseEntity.ok(courseService.getCourseById(id));
}
```

My Request and response classes.

```
@Data   
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CourseIdsRequest {
    private List<Long> courseIds;
}


@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class CoursesByIdResponse {
    List<Course> courses;
}
```

I have no idea what it could be.

Comment: How you are passing ids ? It seems like you are trying to read from RequestBody

Comment: Class CourseIds request holds a list of ids